# Adding WebAPI to an existing MVC Project - getting 404 on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There were many suggested questions/answers when adding this. I went through a bunch and none seemed to help.

I am sure I am missing something simple, just can't see it.

I have an existing ASP.Net MVC (V5) Site. It's a single page.

I am adding an API Controller (WebAPI 2) to it to handle some ajax posts.

I can't seem to get past the 404 Error when trying to post to my controller.

I am also using Attribute Routing.

Here are the parts of the code I believe you will need to see:

API Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/services")]
public class ServicesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("contact")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SendContact(ContactModel model)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }

}
```

WebApiConfig - couple of parts commented out as i try things.

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {

        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        //configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

And my global.cs - again commented out things i've tried

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
//WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

When attempting to post to the api i receive:

```
POST http://localhost:8085/api/services/contact 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

before

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

so it should be:

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Comment: God dammit... Thank you! I KNEW it was something simple! Thanks again.